# How can I save a Blazor Component instance in a variable and render it in my .cshtml

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Considering I have a class called `Tab`.

```
public class Tab
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    protected Tab()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

I want to strictly couple these tabs to a Blazor Component instance and render those instances by iterating over the tabs. I want to have control over when a Component is created and when it is destroyed again.

I want to do this because that way I can **persist the state** for each component.

Here is the problem with the easy approach. Considering something like this:

```
@code {
    public void CreateNewTabAndRemoveOldTab()
    {
        Tabs.RemoveAt(0);
        Tabs.Add(new Tab());
    }
}

foreach (var tab in Tabs)
{
    <MyTabComponent/>
}
```

The newly created tab will simply take over the state of the removed tab. `OnInitialized` will not be called.

I have looked into `RenderFragment`, but it does not look like its working property. The problem is that the Blazor Framework will still decide when a new component is created (thus calling `OnInitialized`) or when existing instance are used.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, Tab is a class, not a component.  You need to decouple your list of Tabs from the component that renders them.  Your list of tabs lives  in a service, the scope depends on what you're doing with them.  Your Tab Component displays the currently selected Tab in the list. If you show a little more of your logic I can probably show you a relevant working example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

@ref it's reference to your component it's added to list of components.

```
@implements IDisposable

@foreach (var tab in tabs)
{
    <MyTabComponent @ref=@TabRef Tab=@tab />
}

@code {

    List<Tab> tabs = new List<Tab>();
    List<MyTabComponent> tabsComp = new List<MyTabComponent>();

    MyTabComponent TabRef {
        set { tabsComp.Add(value); }
    }

    public void CreateNewTabAndRemoveOldTab()
    {
        tabs.RemoveAt(0);
        tabs.Add(new Tab());
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**MyTabs.razor**

```
       <CascadingValue Value="@this" IsFixed="true">
        foreach (var tab in Tabs)
        {
            <MyTabComponent/>
        }
        </CascadingValue>
    
    @code{
    private List<MyTabComponent> Tabs;
    
    public void Register(MyTabComponent tab)
            {
                this.Tabs.Add(tab);
    }
    
    public void UnRegister(MyTabComponent tab)
            {
                this.Tabs.Remove(tab);
    }
    }
```

**MyTabComponent.razor**

```
@implements IDisposable
<div></div>

@code{
[CascadingParameter]
protected MyTabs Context { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Context?.Register(this);
//  implement your logic here
        }

public void Dispose()
        {
            Context?.UnRegister(this);
//  implement your logic here
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.